# Index of row DataGridView

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview

I have a question how can I get an index of currently clicked row of `DataGridView`? I know it simple using:

```
int selectedRowIndex = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Index;
```

But I filtering my `DataGridView` using `ComboBox` for example by Name and when I click on first row I still getting a data from first row of all, not only filtering :/. How can I solve this?

For example I have 4 rows:

```
Name  | City
John  | New York
John  | London
Sarah | Berlin
Sarah | Paris
Tom   | Moscow
```

After filtering by name, for example 'Sarah' I get:

```
Name  | City
Sarah | Berlin
Sarah | Paris
```

And after clicked to first filtered row (Sarah, Berlin) I still get a first row of all (John, New York).

Comment: looks solution to this problem is already discussed [here](https://forums.asp.net/t/1194330.aspx?Problem+selecting+GridView+row+after+filters+were+applied+)

Answer (score 0):

DataGridView has many event eg. OnCellClick or something like that, 
and in the event you have e.RowIndex
event args which you can use.